# "Remote kubernetes server unreachable" error in WSL/Ubuntu but not Command Prompt?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rancher-desktop

So right now I am using Rancher Desktop to run Kubernetes and I keep getting an error in WSL saying "Remote kubernetes server unreachable".  The kubectl commands also take a long time to respond.  However when I tried to run the same commands in Windows Command Prompt, the responses are quick and I don't get the same "server unreachable" error.

I went ahead and ran "kubectl config view" on both terminals and this is what I found.

Command Prompt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN4wx.jpg

WSL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLpSz.jpg

*(sorry for the imgur links, they wouldn't let me post images)*

Also, I only have one context (rancher-desktop) and I made sure both terminals were set to that.